# The output of the following C program should be 3, but I am getting 0 why?

Tags: c, printf

```
main()
{
printf ("%d",(3.0/2)*2) ;
}
```

The output of the following C program should be 3. Why am I getting 0?

Comment: In short: undefined behavior. You're using `%d` for something that's not an int. The result is unpredictable. Use a floating point format specifier.

Comment: Not a full duplicate I'd say, as the implicit conversion to `double` is not obvious to everybody, I suspect. @Mat

Answer (score 5):

The directive `%d` expects an integer (of type `int`), but you're passing a floating-point value (of type `double`).

Depending on the compiler, the processor, the exact content of the program, and the phase of the moon, this could do anything (it's undefined behavior): crash, print some bogus value, [make daemons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)… Here, it happens that the compiler generates code that fetches an integer value from somewhere which happens to contain the value 0 at that point.

To print the floating-point value, change the printf directive:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf ("%f", (3.0/2)*2);
}
```

To print an integer, convert the argument with a cast:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf ("%d", (int)((3.0/2)*2));
}
```

Good compilers warn you when you make such mistakes. Make sure to turn up your compiler's warning level.

Answer (score 0):

Change 3.0/2 to 3.0/2.0

```
printf("%d",(int)((3.0/2.0)*2));
```

Comment: The `2.0` makes no difference

Comment: Your cast is at the wrong place. Your solution will give `2`. Only if you do `printf("%d",(int)((3.0/2.0)*2));`, you'll get 3.
`